# Why is this counted as mutating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
handleClick(event) {
let value = event.target.value;

this.setState({ question: (this.state.question += value) });
```

I get a warning:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state

if I try to load the page with this code.
How can I fix it so it doesn't give me this warning?
It says to use `this.setState`, but that's what I'm doing.

Comment: this.state.question + value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing an unnecessary [assignment addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2) to `this.state.question` - you only need addition here. Furthermore, when updating state based on a previous value, [the docs state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

The proper way to update state based on a previous value is to pass in an update function that works off the previous value, i.e.:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ question: prevState.question + value }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here :

```
this.state.question += value
```

+= is the operator used to add right operand to the left operand. You are trying to add value to this.state.question.

The correct way to do it is :

```
this.setState(previousState => ({ question: previousState.question + value }));
```

Comment: Generally, true, though I would suggest using the function version of `setState` since it's being modified based on previous state. Something like this: `this.setState(state => ({ question: state.question + value }));`. This will become more necessary once Concurrent React is released.

Comment: @Namoz If I do that then the state only updates for the 2nd last button I pressed not the last one. For example (it's a calculator) when it's += it displays the last button I pressed. When I changed it to + it only showed the 2nd last button.

Answer (score 0):

This is considered mutating state because you are assigning a value to `this.state.question` in the expression `(this.state.question += value)`. I have pasted a link to a Code Sandbox you can view to see how to correctly implement this behavior.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/535xnw27ox)