# Trying to display one element from an Array -ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a flashcard web app for language learning and/or rote learning. I have managed to show the first element of the array which contains the data that I'm fetching from the backend but I can't switch from the first element to the subsequent elements.

Here is my code in React:

```
// Decklist component that displays the flashcard
import { React, useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import cardContext from "../store/cardContext";
const axios = require("axios");

export default function Decklist() {
  //State for data fetched from db
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  //State for array element to be displayed from the "data" state
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);

  //function to change the array element to be displayed after user reads card
  const setVisibility = () => {
    setPosition(position++);
  };

  //function to change the difficulty of a card
  const difficultyHandler = (difficulty, id) => {
    console.log(difficulty);
    setData(
      data.map((ele) => {
        if (ele.ID === id) {
          return { ...ele, type: difficulty };
        }
        return ele;
      })
    );
  };

  //useEffect for fetching data from db
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/cards")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data) {
          console.log(res.data);
          setData(res.data.sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1)));
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <cardContext.Provider
      value={{ cardData: data, setDifficulty: difficultyHandler }}
    >
      {data.length && (
        <Card
          position={position}
          // dataIndex={index}
          visible={setVisibility}
          id={data[position].ID}
          front={data[position].Front}
          back={data[position].Back}
        />
      )}
    </cardContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
//Card component
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Options from "./Options";

export default function Card(props) {
  //State for showing or hiding the answer
  const [reverse, setReverse] = useState(false);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(true);

  //function for showing the answer
  const reversalHandler = () => {
    setReverse(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {reverse ? (
        <div className="card">
          {props.front} {props.back}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              props.visible();
            }}
          >
            Next Card
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="card">{props.front}</div>
      )}
      <Options
        visible={props.visible}
        reverse={reversalHandler}
        id={props.id}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//Options Component
import { React, useContext, useState } from "react";
import cardContext from "../store/cardContext";

export default function Options(props) {
  const ctx = useContext(cardContext);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={display ? "" : "inactive"}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDisplay(false);
            props.reverse();
            ctx.setDifficulty("easy", props.id);
          }}
        >
          Easy
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDisplay(false);
            props.reverse();
            ctx.setDifficulty("medium", props.id);
          }}
        >
          Medium
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDisplay(false);
            props.reverse();
            ctx.setDifficulty("hard", props.id);
          }}
        >
          Hard
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The setVisibility function in the Decklist component is working fine and setting the position state properly. However, I don't know how to re-render the Card component so that it acts on the position state that has changed.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058288/why-is-this-counted-as-mutating-state) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to force a re-render of a component is to set its state to itself

```
    onClick={() => {
              props.visible();
              setReverse(reverse);
            }}
```

However this probably isn't your issue as components will automatically re-render when their state changes or a parent re-renders. This means that for some reason the Card component isn't actually changing the parent component.

Comment: Do know of any common reasons for the component not changing the parent component?